# AuthSub: (404, 'Not Found', 'Unknown user.')

Tags: python, django, gdata, authsub

I try  to use Picasa API with AuthSub. My code:

```
GD_CLIENT = gdata.photos.service.PhotosService()

def login(request):
    def GetAuthSubUrl():
        callback = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback'
        scope = 'https://picasaweb.google.com/data/'
        secure = False
        session = True
        return GD_CLIENT.GenerateAuthSubURL(callback, scope, secure, session)

    auth_sub_url = GetAuthSubUrl()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(auth_sub_url)


def confirm(request):
    authsub_token = request.GET['token']    
    token = GD_CLIENT.SetAuthSubToken(authsub_token)
    GD_CLIENT.UpgradeToSessionToken()
    GD_CLIENT.auth_token = token
    return direct_to_template(request, 'base.djhtml')


def add_album(request):
   form = AddAlbum(request.POST or None)
   if form.is_valid():
       data = form.cleaned_data
       title = data.get('title')
       summary = data.get('summary')
       GD_CLIENT.InsertAlbum(title=title, summary=summary)
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/get_albums/')
   return render(request, 'add_form.djhtml', {'form': form})
```

I got an error at add_album:

> (404, 'Not Found', 'Unknown user.')
>
> Traceback:
>   File "/home/i159/Envs/photorulez/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
>     111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>   File "/home/i159/workspace/photorulez/photorulez/photoapp/views.py" in add_album
>     49.         GD_CLIENT.InsertAlbum(title=title, summary=summary)
>   File "/home/i159/Envs/photorulez/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gdata/photos/service.py" in InsertAlbum
>     358.       raise GooglePhotosException(e.args[0])
>
> Exception Type: GooglePhotosException at /add_album/
>   Exception Value: (404, 'Not Found', 'Unknown user.')

Why is it raised? What changes are needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!!! GD_CLIENT = gdata.photos.service.PhotosService() needed `email` keyword argument as Google account user name.

gdata.photos.sevice.py

```
class PhotosService(gdata.service.GDataService):
  ssl = True
  userUri = '/data/feed/api/user/%s'

  def __init__(self, email=None, password=None, source=None,
           server='picasaweb.google.com', additional_headers=None,
           **kwargs):
```

So it should be:

```
GD_CLIENT = gdata.photos.service.PhotosService(email='username')
```

Comment: you can accept you answer as being correct - click the green box on the left

Answer (score 0):

This is my function to authenticate a user that i have a session token:

```
def get_client(authsub_token):
    gd_client = gdata.photos.service.PhotosService(email='default')

    gd_client.SetAuthSubToken(authsub_token)

    return gd_client
```

If you put the email, or username as 'default' he will use the user that authorized the token