# Picasa Web Albums REST API: 404 Unknown User issue

Tags: google-api, google-api-client, picasa, google-photos

I'm trying to get the list of albums as it is written here: https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol#ListPhotos

GET https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default
Authorization: Bearer MY_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE

So, the problem is that I get "404 Unknown user" responce. Strange thing but when I make the same request with the same access token from another PC, I get the correct responce (200 OK and list of albums).

I didn't google anything useful except the similar issue which was on API for Python (like here: [AuthSub: (404, 'Not Found', 'Unknown user.')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766566/authsub-404-not-found-unknown-user)). Did anyone face the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was that Google Photos server handles the requests incorrectly, if these requests contain some wrong Cookie headers.
I say "incorrectly" because other Google APIs (like Drive, Contacts, etc.) didn't have this issue.

So, all that I had to do is to add flag INTERNET_FLAG_NO_COOKIES in InternetOpenUrl function:

```
InternetOpenUrl(NetHandle, PChar(Url), PChar(Header), Length(Header), INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD or INTERNET_FLAG_NO_COOKIES, 0);
```

After that sending HTTP requests using InternetOpenUrl with the flag won't return this error anymore.